# Convert array to nested array object based on its depth value?

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript object:

this is basically a list of comments, the actual list is much longer and more deeply nested, so this is a simplified version.

```js
[
    {
        id: 200,
        comment: "If you have any question, please comment here.",
        depth: 1,
        parent_id: null, 
        comments: [],
    },
    {
        id: 201,
        comment: "Hi, I'm stuck at the installation of node.js. Can I ask help?",
        depth: 2,
        parent_id: 200, 
        comments: [],
    },
    {
        id: 202,
        comment: "This is a detailed explanation, great.",
        depth: 1,
        parent_id: null, 
        comments: [],
    },
    {
        id: 203,
        comment: "Hello! That's weird. Do you have a screenshot?",
        depth: 3,
        parent_id: 201, 
        comments: [],
    },
]
```

I want to convert the above to the following. But I think I use .map or similar, but I don't have a clear idea of how to implement this.

```js
[
    {
        id: 200,
        comment: "If you have any question, please comment here.",
        depth: 1,
        parent_id: null, 
        comments: [
            {
                id: 201,
                comment: "Hi, I'm stuck at the installation of node.js. Can I ask help?",
                depth: 2,
                parent_id: 200, 
                comments: [                    
                    {
                        id: 203,
                        comment: "Hello! That's weird. Do you have a screenshot?",
                        depth: 3,
                        parent_id: 201, 
                        comments: [],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        id: 202,
        comment: "This is a detailed explanation, great.",
        depth: 1,
        parent_id: null, 
        comments: [],
    },
]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

a solution with array.reduce

```js
var data = [
    {
        id: 200,
        comment: "If you have any question, please comment here.",
        depth: 1,
        parent_id: null, 
        comments: [],
    },
    {
        id: 201,
        comment: "Hi, I'm stuck at the installation of node.js. Can I ask help?",
        depth: 2,
        parent_id: 200, 
        comments: [],
    },
    {
        id: 202,
        comment: "This is a detailed explanation, great.",
        depth: 1,
        parent_id: null, 
        comments: [],
    },
    {
        id: 203,
        comment: "Hello! That's weird. Do you have a screenshot?",
        depth: 3,
        parent_id: 201, 
        comments: [],
    },
];


const result = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let parent = (curr.parent_id) ? data.filter(el => el.id === curr.parent_id) : [];
  if (parent.length) {
    parent[0].comments.push(curr);
  } else {
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach to seem to work is by using a double loop with `forEach()` and a conditional statement to push the elements inside the `comments` array if conditions are met.

```js
let data = [
    {
        id: 200,
        comment: "If you have any question, please comment here.",
        depth: 1,
        parent_id: null, 
        comments: [],
    },
    {
        id: 201,
        comment: "Hi, I'm stuck at the installation of node.js. Can I ask help?",
        depth: 2,
        parent_id: 200, 
        comments: [],
    },
    {
        id: 202,
        comment: "This is a detailed explanation, great.",
        depth: 1,
        parent_id: null, 
        comments: [],
    },
    {
        id: 203,
        comment: "Hello! That's weird. Do you have a screenshot?",
        depth: 3,
        parent_id: 201, 
        comments: [],
    },
]

data.forEach((el_one) => {
  data.forEach((el_two) => {
    if(el_one.parent_id === el_two.id){
     el_two.comments.push(el_one)  
    }
  })
})

console.log(data)
```

Comment: i think you should sort() data by depth first :

Answer (score 0):

Create a plain object with elements, walk through your array and place all children elements into the `comments` field accessing corresponding parent element via that plain object. Then filter out all non-root elements (i assume your data is stored in the array named `data`):

```js
// Fill in id-accessed storage
var elements_by_id = {};
data.forEach((el) => elements_by_id[el.id] = el );

// Feed comments
data.forEach((el) => el.parent_id ? ( elements_by_id[el.parent_id].comments.push(el) ) : '' );

// Remove non-root elements
data = data.filter( (el) => !el.parent_id );
```